# How do I close or reset via arduino code?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, arduino, pyserial

Well I want to print what has data in arduino right? I already tried with ser.close () as it is in the code and it does not work, it's the printe when I reboot the arduino, doing the whole process of pressing the button on the arduino. I would like to know how to reset or otherwise close the correct way for you to start the code.

```
def getSerialData(self):

    lines=b''

    with serial.Serial('COM5',9600) as ser:      
        while (ser.inWaiting()<0): #Do while loop waiting for data 
            time.sleep(0.1)
        tempo = 20.0
        endtime=time.time()+tempo
        time.sleep(tempo-15.0)
        print("tempo")
        while (time.time()<endtime):
            print("entrou")
            time.sleep(0.1)
            line = ser.readline()
            #line = line.encode("utf-8")
            lines += line
            #lines += bytes(line, 'utf-8')
    ser.close()
    print("saiu")
    lin = lines.split()
    print(lin)
```

Comment: Do you want to soft reset your Arduino board from your Python script?

Comment: Exactly, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You have some option to reset your arduino hardware

- Using 1 Wire Connected to the RESET Pin
- Using Just Software

  void(* resetFunc) (void) = 0;//declare reset function at address 0
  resetFunc(); //call reset

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control your Arduino board with a Python script you need to first establish a Serial communication and then create a simple protocol to send your commands from Python script to Arduino. For the reset part in Arduino, there are some [ways](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/reset-an-arduino-uno-in-code) to do it and I prefer to using a watchdog timeout.

Arduino Code:

```
#include <avr/wdt.h>


void setup()
{
    MCUSR = 0;  // clear out any flags of prior resets.
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

// read a command from serial and do proper action
void read_command()
{
    String command;
    if (Serial.available())
    {
        command = Serial.readString();
        Serial.print("Received Command: ");
        Serial.println(command);
        // do proper work with command
        if (command == "RST")
        {
            Serial.println("Arduino is Reseting...");
            // reset board
            wdt_enable(WDTO_15MS); // turn on the WatchDog and don't stroke it.
            for(;;) { 
            // do nothing and wait for the eventual...
            } 
        }
    }
}

void loop()
{
    // get new commands
    read_command();
    delay(1000);
}
```

Python Script:

```
import serial
from time import sleep


# remember to set this value to a proper serial port name
ser = serial.Serial('COM1', 9600)
ser.open()
# flush serial for unprocessed data
ser.flushInput()
while True:
   command = "RST"
   ser.write(command.encode())
   """
   # use below code if you want to take commands from user
   command = input("Enter your command: ")
   if command:
      command += "\r\n"
      ser.write(command.encode())
   """
   ser.flushInput()
   sleep(3)
```